# Marlin 2.0.5 compiling error collect2.exe

Tags: arduino, ide

I get the following error when I compile the code:

```
C:\Users\REMYCO~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccf1AtyI.ltrans0.ltrans.o: In function `main':

C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino/main.cpp:43: undefined reference to `setup'

C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino/main.cpp:46: undefined reference to `loop'

collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

exit status 1
Error compiling for board Arduino Mega or Mega 2560.
```

I'm a total beginner, so I have no idea what to do about it...

Answer (score 1):

You try to compile a version which is not prepared for the ArduinoIDE, probably try with PlatformIO. The loop() routine is missing, which ArduinoIDE needs for compiling. Read the instructions of the Marlin version, which environment to use for compiling and flashing.

As a step by step check:
You have the lastest version from here:

```
https://github.com/MarlinFirmware/Marlin
```

You have ArduinoIDE stable latest:(as of 23.3.2020) 1.8.12
You have the latest core for your board (e.g. for MEGA based): v 1.8.2 
Check if the used libraries are the latest.
Load marlin.ino (from the source above) 
Choose the correct board (e.g. MEGA), the correct settings and try again.

If it still throws the same error check your IDE and make a clean install.

Comment: Strange, because I used ArduinoIDE for the previous version I uploaded to my 3d printer. ArduinoIDE is also the same software used by all 3d printing youtube channel.